# Number format exception in Java: unknown hex number

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I`m working on a project and I had to convert a hex String to a binary String I used a lot of methods but the code below was the most useful to me although this code creates an unknown hex number "l" which looks like 1 but is not one, does some one know what this thing is(l)? and how did it appear and how to fix it and convert it to "1" ?

```
public String hexToBin(String hex){
String bin =new String();
String binFragment =new String();
int iHex;
hex = hex.trim();
hex = hex.replaceFirst("0x","");

for(int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++){
    iHex = Integer.parseInt(""+hex.charAt(i),16);
    binFragment = Integer.toBinaryString(iHex);

    while(binFragment.length() < 4){
        binFragment = "0" + binFragment;
    }
    bin += binFragment;
}
```

Comment: Please show your full error message here.

Comment: `hex` contains `l`, and it cannot be parsed as `int`.

Comment: where's the return statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Integer.decode()` instead of `Integer.parseInt()` as it handles hex strings as well.
See; [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: They both handle hex.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BigInteger.toString(radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29). The radix being what base you want to use. So with binary, also known as base2, fill in 2.

```
static String hexToBin(String s) {
  return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
}
```